# MouseOver expand effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, flash

Please visit the following website( www.capitec.co.za ) and hoover with your mouse over the items on the home page. You will notice they expand, I would like to know how I can do this on my website as I failed using css. Is it jquery, javascript and they used adobe to create this please assist with examples if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

Supposing a div `.element` which you want to expand on mouse over

```
<div class="element">
    // you content
</div>
```

This is a css only solution and below css would be beneficial

```
.element:hover{
    transform:scale(1.1,1.1);
}
```

> The initial values of scale are `scale(1,1)` the div will expand according to the increases values of scale.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which browsers you need to support, you can use the `transform:scale()` css function, and invoke this on `:hover` of a the element you want to expand

Answer (score 0):

Use the `transform: scale` CSS to have expand effect on hover. You can add transition css to scale it slowly as below:

```
<div class="expand"> Hover me to expand </div>


.expand {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: coral;
    margin: 2em;
    padding: 1em;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
    transition: transform 1s;
}
.expand:hover {

    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```